# how to get order collection object in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm beginner in magento2 and I'll try to retrieve all order related
        Information and that information just want to display on admin side
        like order's Id, order status , store name , order date , 
        payment method , etc.
        Here,I try to get order information like order id , order status but
        page will be redirect to home page / dashboard.

I get product related information using product Collection object but how I get all order information.

I don't know how to get order information using order collection
        object or order repository object and that order information display
        on admin side in magento2.

Here is my view or `info.phtml` file is :

```
<?php     $_order = $block->getOrder(3);
$orderAdminDate = $block->formatDate(
$block->getOrderAdminDate($_order->getCreatedAt()),
\IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, true );
echo 'Order Status = '.$_order->getStatusLabel();
echo 'Order Id = '. $_order->getRealOrderId();    ?>
```

And here is my `Info.php` block file is :

```
class Info extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder
{
public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
array $data = []
) {    $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
parent::__construct($context, $adminHelper, $data);
}
public function getOrder()
{    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');    }    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In your Block file

```
namespace "Your Module namespace";
class modelclass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory */
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
   /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection */
   protected $orders;
   public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,  \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory, array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;     
    parent::__construct($context, $data);        
}

public function getOrders() {        
        if (!$this->orders) 
        {
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');
        }
        return $this->orders;
}
```

> In your phtml file

```
$_orders = $block->getOrders();
if ($_orders && count($_orders)) {
$complete = $pending = $closed = $canceled = $processing = $onHold = 0;
foreach ($_orders as $_order) {
$label = $_order->getStatusLabel();
switch ($label) {
        case 'Complete' : $complete++;
            break;
        case 'Pending' : $pending++;
            break;
        case 'Processing' : $processing++;
            break;
        case 'Canceled' : $canceled++;
            break;
        case 'Closed' : $closed++;
            break;
    }
}
    echo "Order Status <br>";
    echo "Completed Order " . $complete . "<br>";
    echo "Pending Order " . $pending . "<br>";
    echo "Closed Order " . $closed . "<br>";
    echo "Canceled Order " . $canceled . "<br>";
    echo "Processing Order" . $processing . "<br>";
}
else{
 echo "You have no Orders";
}
```

Comment: This no longer work with M2.2. It gives error "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null"

Answer (score 5):

You can go through below code

```
<?php
 namespace 'moduleNameSpace';
class ModelClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
}

protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')

}
   public function getSalesOrderCollection(array $filters = []){

    return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
}       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's work but I find earlier solution for that and that is below

Comment: There is a foreach missing in your getSalesOrderCollection-function.

Answer (score 3):

get your all order information

```
  public function __construct(
   \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger,
   \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $_orderModel

    ) {
    $this->_logger = $_logger;
    $this->_orderModel = $_orderModel;

  }
  public function getOrders($store){
    $orders = $this->_orderModel->getCollection();
    $orders->join(array('item' => 'sales_order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = item.order_id AND main_table.store_id='.$store.' ');
    $orders->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
    $orders->getSelect()->order('main_table.created_at DESC');
    $this->_logger->info($orders); //find your query in system.log
    $order_array = array();
        foreach($orders as $k=>$order) {
                    $order_array[$k] = array(
                        'order_id' => $order->getId(),
                        'order_incremental_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                        'order_status' => $order->getStatusLabel(),
                        'order_date' => $order->getCreatedAt(),
                        'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName()
                        //as your need
                    );
        }
     return json_encode($order_array);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, **@taps** Thnks for your reply but it's not working for me.Gives error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace namespace\modulename\Model\Config\Source;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory;
class OrderStatus implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $options = null;
    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
          CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if ($this->options === null) {
            $status = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            foreach ($status as $stat) {
                $this->options[] = [
                    'value' => $stat->getStatus(),
                    'label' => $stat->getLabel(),
                ];
            }
        }
        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

Comment: use this code for to load sales order collection in your module.the result will display in store->config in magento2

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
print_r($orderDatamodel1->getData());

}
```

Comment: it will be better to add some clarifications and not only code snippet, So others can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the SQL query where you will get the placed order data details accordingly item wise, which means you will get the report item wise in Magento2 by SQL Query:-

> SELECT so.increment_id
>   AS OrderId, 
>          so.status                                                  AS 
>          Order_Status, 
>          soi.sku                                                    AS Sku, 
>          soi.original_price                                         AS MRP_WithTax 
>          , 
>          soi.qty_ordered                                            AS 
>          Qty_Order, 
>          soi.price                                                  AS MRP_WTP, 
>          soi.discount_percent                                       AS 
>          Discount_Percent, 
>          soi.discount_amount                                        AS 
>          Discount_Amount, 
>          so.shipping_amount                                         AS 
>          ShippingAmount, 
>          soi.price_incl_tax * soi.qty_ordered - soi.discount_amount AS RowTotal, 
>          soi.tax_percent                                            AS Taxpercent, 
>          soi.tax_amount                                             AS TaxAmount, 
>          sig.increment_id                                           AS InvoiceId, 
>          sig.created_at                                             AS InvoiceDate 
>          , 
>          CASE 
>            WHEN sig.increment_id = sig.increment_id THEN 'Paid' 
>            ELSE 'NonPaid' 
>          END                                                        AS status  FROM   sales_order so 
>          LEFT JOIN sales_order_address soa 
>                 ON so.shipping_address_id = soa.entity_id 
>          LEFT JOIN sales_order_item soi 
>                 ON so.entity_id = soi.order_id 
>          LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product ccp 
>                 ON soi.product_id = ccp.product_id 
>          LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar ccev 
>                 ON ccp.category_id = ccev.entity_id 
>          LEFT JOIN sales_invoice_grid sig 
>                 ON sig.order_increment_id = so.increment_id  WHERE ( so.created_at BETWEEN '2017-03-01 'AND '2019-03-01' )  GROUP  BY
>   soi.item_id

You have just copy and paste in PHPMYADMIN in SQL formatter, get the data according to the date filter.

I hope it will help, let me know if you have any concern or query.